# Colors in Python

Tags: python, colors

I am learning Python and would like to know if there is something in such a language that does the same thing as "#define" in C, as the example below:

```
#define cor_preta     "\033[30m"
#define cor_vermelha  "\033[31m"
#define cor_verde     "\033[32m"
#define cor_amarela   "\033[33m"
#define cor_azul      "\033[34m"
#define cor_magenta   "\033[35m"
#define cor_ciano     "\033[36m"
#define cor_branca    "\033[37m"
```

Comment: `cor_preta = "\033[30m"` etc?

Comment: Also you can look at [`enum.Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html). Also there are multiple python packages that facilitate working with ANSI escape codes that already have done that

Comment: For this specific usage (colored output to terminal), I would recommend [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/).

Comment: I guess you would then like to "concatenate" those in your code. You might also have a look into "f-strings". Or the the str `format` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare these as normal variables in the global scope

```
cor_preta    = "\033[30m"
cor_vermelha = "\033[31m"
cor_verde    = "\033[32m"
cor_amarela  = "\033[33m"
cor_azul     = "\033[34m"
cor_magenta  = "\033[35m"
cor_ciano    = "\033[36m"
cor_branca   = "\033[37m"

def main():
    print(cor_ciano)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, be aware of global variables because it can possibly cause you some troubles when interacting with local scopes. You can read more about global and local scopes [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables#:%7E:text=In%20Python%2C%20a%20variable%20declared,variable%20is%20created%20in%20Python.) or [here (in portuguese)](https://giovannireisnunes.wordpress.com/2017/07/28/variaveis-globais-em-python/).